# How can I check to see the number of iterations Newton's method takes to run?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So basically I want to grab the number of iterations it takes my newton's method to find the root, and then take that number and apply it to my color scheme to make the longer the amount of iterations, the darker the color, and the fewer, the more full the color.

so here's my code

```
from numpy import *
import pylab as pl
def myffp(x):
    return x**3 - 1, 3*(x**2)    
def newton( ffp, x, nits):
    for i in range(nits):
        #print i,x
        f,fp = ffp(x)
        x = x - f/fp
    return x    
q = sqrt(3)/2
def leggo(xmin=-1,xmax=1,jmin=-1,jmax=1,pts=1000,nits=30):
    x = linspace(xmin, xmax, pts)
    y = linspace(jmin, jmax, pts)*complex(0,1)
    x1,y1 = meshgrid(x,y)                   
    n = newton(myffp,x1+y1,nits)                  #**here is where i wanna see the number of iterations newton's method takes to find my root** 
    r1 = complex(1,0)  
    r2 = complex(-.5, q)
    r3 = complex(-.5,-q)
    data = zeros((pts,pts,3))   
    data[:,:,0] = abs(n-r1)         #**and apply it here**
    data[:,:,2] = abs(n-r2)
    data[:,:,1] = abs(n-r3)
    pl.show(pl.imshow(data))    
leggo()
```

The main problem is finding the number of iterations, I can then figure out how to apply that to darkening the color, but for now it's just finding the number of iterations it takes for each value ran through newton's method.

Comment: Kevin: it looks like you aren't sure how to *accept* answers to your SO Questions. It's simple but not so obvious when you are new to SO. Here's how to do it: if you find that an answer has been helpful to you, then move your mouse over the upper left-hand corner of that answer (where the answer "score" appears between two gray triangles). When you mouseover the score, you will see an outline of a "check". click that check mark to "accept" that answer. You will then see a solid green check by the answerer's score and +2 points added to your score.

Comment: I'm not super satisfied? None of them actually answered my question. They are definitely solid answers, but i'm looking for something that uses a tolerance, and stops the newton method and finally returns how many iterations it takes to stop the method. The one answer by you doug (with the eps and old x) looks promising, but I just couldn't implement it into my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to just refactor your *newton* function so that it keeps track of the total iterations and then returns it (along with the result, of course), e.g.,

```
def newton( ffp, x, nits):
    c = 0                   # initialize iteration counter
    for i in range(nits):
        c += 1              # increment counter for each iteration 
        f, fp = ffp(x)
        x = x - f/fp
    return x, c             # return the counter when the function is called
```

so in the main body of your code, *change* your call to *newton*, like so:

```
res, tot_iter = newton(myffp, x, nits)
```

the number of iterations in the last call to newton is stored in **tot_iter**

---

As aside, your implementation of *Newton's Method* seems to be incomplete.

for instance, it's missing a test against some convergence criterion.

Here's a simple implementation in python that works:

```
def newtons_method(x_init, fn, max_iter=100):
    """
    returns: approx. val of root of the function passed in, fn;
    pass in: x_init, initial value for the root; 
    max_iter, total iteration count not exceeded;
    fn, a function of the form: 
    def f(x): return x**3 - 2*x
    """
    x = x_init
    eps = .0001
    # set initial value different from x_init so at lesat 1 loop
    x_old = x + 10 * eps        
    step = .1
    c = 0
    # (x - x_old) is convergence criterion
    while (abs(x - x_old) > eps) and (c < max_iter):
        c += 1
        fval = fn(x)
        dfdx = (fn(x + step)) - fn(x) / step
        x_old = x
        x = x_old - fval / dfdx
    return x, c
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you're currently using for `newton()` has a fixed number of iterations (`nits` - which is being passed in as 30), so the results would be kind of trivial and uninteresting.

It looks like you're trying to generate a Newton fractal -- the method you're trying to use is incorrect; the typical coloring mode is based on the output of the function, not the number of iterations. See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal) for a full explanation.

Comment: Right, I know what you're saying. I'm just trying to see if I can get the number of iterations to get to the root. Example
I have a starting point x, or in the case of my code, x1+y1, and I want to know how many iterations it takes the newton method to get to a desired root. The program runs 30 iterations regardless, but I just want to see if I can somehow grab the number it takes to get the final result, and then it'll just return that result another say 20 times

Comment: In all but a few lucky situations, it never does. It just gets successively closer (hopefully!) with each iteration.

Comment: This is a little late to the conversation, but you are correct - @duskwuff - when you say that he will get a fixed number of iterations each call and that is uninteresting.  You are incorrect to say that the number of iterations will not produce a fractal.  It does produce lovely fractals!

Comment: @mrKelley: If the number of iterations is always 30, and you graph the number of iterations for each point… they'll all be 30. As I noted, the Newton fractal is produced by graphing which value the algorithm converges to, not how long it takes to get there.